# Void pointer to struct and accessing members

Tags: c, struct, casting, void

I am fiddling around with and learning about void pointers and linked lists and I think I may have to concept and application a little wrong.

Currently, I have a void pointer which points to the address of a struct in memory. I am then trying to access this struct via casting the void pointer to that struct. However, I am not getting the expected value only *0*.

Code is as follows.

```
void *data = ListGetItemAtIndex(freeList, i); // returns void *
memoryBlock *block = (memoryBlock *) data;
printf("%ld\n\n", block->startAddress);
```

The struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t startAddress;
    size_t memory;
} memoryBlock;
```

Address when struct was added:

```
0x5593c4812720
```

Address of void *:

```
0x5593c4812720
```

The question at heart is, how do I use this void pointer to access the data in the struct.

Requested example :

Block creation

```
static memoryBlock* CreateMemoryBlockPointer(size_t startAdress, size_t size)
{
    memoryBlock block;

    block.startAddress = startAdress;
    block.memory = size;

    return malloc(sizeof(block));
}
```

Assignment:

```
memoryBlock *ptr = CreateMemoryBlockPointer(StartAddress, size);

// Add initial 1st element
ListAddTail(freeList, ptr);
```

Prototype:

```
int ListAddTail(linkedList *list, void* data)
```

Add to list

```
   el->data = data;
   el->next = NULL;
```

Comment: The code under *Code is as follows* is correct, that's how you access your struct if you only have a void pointer to the struct. What is your question?

Comment: My question is why my code is currently not returning the expected value of 1000 instead its returning 0

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]. There may be bugs in the code you didn't show.

Comment: `return malloc(sizeof(block));` returns newly allocated, uninitialized memory. It does **not** contain the values you wrote into the local `block` variable

Comment: Oooh gosh you're right. A little brainfart there. How would I go about accessing those members. Pardon the simple question but my brain does not appear to understand this very well

Comment: @UnholySheep sorry forgot the tag

Comment: Allocate the memory first, then write into the memory, e.g.: `memoryBlock *block = malloc(sizeof(*block)); block->startAddress = startAddress;` etc. then `return block;` at the end of the function

Comment: THANK YOU, I LOVE YOU <3 @UnholySheep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, see :

> Allocate the memory first, then write into the memory, e.g.:
>
> ```
> memoryBlock *block = malloc(sizeof(*block));
> block->startAddress = startAddress;
> ```
>
> etc. then return block; at the end of the function –

- @UnholySheep